# How to capture fmt.Print ouput in a text file in Golang

Tags: go

There are certain `fmt.Print` statements that I want to save into a .txt file.

I don't want to store all print statments. Can I do this ?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/log/#New

Comment: Thanks but I am not logging. These are print statements

Comment: Sorry. Missed that. But it's the same [concept.](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprint)

Comment: No. Too short for an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Create("myfile")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    mw := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, file)
    fmt.Fprintln(mw, "This line will be written to stdout and also to a file")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`fmt.Fprint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprint) method for calls you want to save to a file. There are also [`fmt.Fprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf) and [`fmt.Fprintln()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintln).

These functions take a destination [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) as the first argument, to which you can pass your file ([`*os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File)).

For example:

```
f, err := os.Create("data.txt")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer f.Close()

fmt.Println("This goes to standard output.")
fmt.Fprintln(f, "And this goes to the file")
fmt.Fprintf(f, "Also to file, with some formatting. Time: %v, line: %d\n",
    time.Now(), 2)
```

If you want all `fmt.PrintXX()` calls to go to the file which you have no control over (e.g. you can't change them to `fmt.FprintXX()` because they are part of another library), you may change `os.Stdout` temporarily, so all further `fmt.PrintXX()` calls will write to the output you set, e.g.:

```
// Temporarily set your file as the standard output (and save the old)
old, os.Stdout = os.Stdout, f

// Now all fmt.PrintXX() calls output to f
somelib.DoSomething()

// Restore original standard output
os.Stdout = old
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use Openfile instead of Open? From the doc (https://pkg.go.dev/os#Open) I read that Open opns the file read only. How do you write to the file in that case?

Comment: @DavidVerdin Yes, you're right. This was an overlook on my part. Fixed it.